# What links Federated Identities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

"The Facebook SDK obtains an OAuth token that Amazon Cognito uses to generate AWS credentials for your authenticated end user. Amazon Cognito also uses the token to check against your user database for the existence of a user matching this particular Facebook identity. If the user already exists, the API returns the existing identifier. Otherwise a new identifier is returned." - AWS Docs

Is Amazon Cognito only checking for the same Facebook user already in the database, or is it checking all users for matching fields, such as email? I am needing to allow for a user to sign in with email, Facebook, or Google and get the same data regardless. Basically I'm asking if Amazon Cognito links the users together automatically by email, or if this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Soo you're about to enter an entire world of pain. In short lets say Marc-at-marc.com registered as a user in the pool then marc-at-marc.com registers via facebook(federated) you can't retrospectively link that identity back. I headed up identity for a large company a while ago and Cognito has some serious pitfalls, aside from the one you've found as I remember you can't search for custom attributes either.

Comment: Good job on spotting this limitation though, I need to check the docs again to make sure what I'm about to say is correct as an answer and if you'd like to talk through how I got round it we can always take it to chat, give me 30 mins to make sure I'm up to date on Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correctly in line with what I've said above - I can't currently see an update to the features that I'm talking about - I'm happy to be wrong but....

Federated identities are very separate things if they're not the same session, in order for an identity to be linked they have to already be logged in with the old one and login with something else - in effect although on paper Cognito looks awesome this is why we hadn't used it, our problems were this:

(replacing @ with !)

marc!marc.com signs into the user pool.

marc!marc.com signs in via facebook.

marc!marc.com signs in via anything else.

You'll probably end up with 3 users if they're three separate sessions - despite what AWS say if you read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) it looks like you can link ID's you can but only if they logged in with the original ID first.

Yes this is silly, yes it really isn't fit for purpose - at a major hotel chain I talked in AWS offices about this and the upgrades **were** on the roadmap - I haven't revisited it since so hopefully I'm wrong!

**NOTE**
Please do not accept this answer for about 24 hours as I'd like to give anyone else the opportunity to chip in, I think I'm 100% correct but I haven't looked at Cognito for a while(and I'm a bit scared to because the docs aren't great(sorry AWS) and it nearly drove me off a cliff last time trying to do exactly what you're trying to).

Comment: Amen to what was said about the AWS docs... We've been stuck on this for quite a while now (sounds like the same problem as you). A possible solution being considered is just giving the separate users an id based on their email, then when a user authenticates just use that ID for accessing resources. Kind of a hack job and it feels like there should be a better way. Not to mention the issues that arise when if emails are changed....

Comment: Personally, IF I am correct I'd create your own user store, I'd use SSM/KMS keys to encrypt the data and custom authorizers in front of your API's I'm happy to offer some advice if you like and then we can talk through it and I'll post back an answer "Marc Fielding" on LinkedIn i'm the guy with tortoise - @mods sorry if this isn't quite cricket but this will result in a decent answer once I can understand the exact use case. Unless we can figure a way to turn this to chat actually, I can't see the link any more?

Comment: We currently have our own user database store in place right now, but it's kind of a mess. One thing that has been really nice about AWS is the Amazon Cognito Auth SDK which simplifies the authentication process nicely. So we'll discuss it more and decide what would be best

Comment: So a custom jwt solution via a custom Lambda authorisation is easy to implement once ya get the add/dent policy generation - but yeah give me a shout if you’d like some input - I can tell you about my experiences

Comment: Hello guys! I am also in stuck with this question, though I am surveying before implementation. I understood that Cognito does not link logins by email and this is awful from practical side, and reasonable from security reason. Latter point left almost no chance to get this implementation in libs from AWS in future.

So, I have only one question left: if several logins can be linked to the same identity - does it mean that if a user logged in using User Pool - then he can add other logins by logging in to other auths, and then such auths will work even if their tokens expired?